# How to get Roslyn Analizer results in VSTS Build Definition?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm working on DevSecOps. Related to that, I want to secure my application with the help of Roslyn Analyzer. For that I created an MVC Web Application along with custom ruleset in Visual Studio and it's working fine with outputs clearly.

But, when I tried to do same thing with the help of VSTS Build task in my Build Definition in VSTS account. By referring the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926915/run-roslyn-code-analyzers-on-build-server), I known that with the help of MSBuild task we can get the Roslyn Analyser results by default. But I didn’t get the results of Roslyn Analyzer results after running my Build Definition. Can you suggest me to “How to overcome this situation”?

Comment: Can you get the results when you run msbuild in command line on your local dev machine?

Answer (score 1):

If that works locally when run msbuild in command line, then you can try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Add a command line task to run the msbuild command line script
  directly.
- Change another hosted agent.
- Deploy an private agent on your dev machine, then check if that works
  with the private agent.

You can also reference below articles to troubleshoot the issue:

- [Using, configuring and distributing Roslyn analysers in teams](http://ivanz.com/2015/09/06/using-roslyn-analysers)
- [Running Code Analyzers on Build Server](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20160604-RunningCodeAnalyzersOnBuildServer.html)