# Roslyn - obtain reference to a string assigned to property

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Throughout Visual Studio Solution with multiple projects, I have code snippets similar to:

```csharp
sqlCommand.CommandText = "Some SQL statement";
```

I am able to obtain all references to `CommandText` being a `Callee` inside of a solution via:

```csharp
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols;
// ...

var project = _solution.GetProject("my-project");
            

var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
var sqlCmdSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(SqlCommand).FullName);
var cmdTextSymbol = sqlCmdSymbol.GetMembers("CommandText").First();

IEnumerable<SymbolCallerInfo> allReferences = await SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(cmdTextSymbol, _solution);
var calledSymbolReferences = allReferences.Where(r => SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(r.CalledSymbol, cmdTextSymbol)).ToArray();

foreach (SymbolCallerInfo reference in calledSymbolReferences)
{
    // How to get from `SymbolCallerInfo` to a `LiteralExpressionSyntax` following it?
    // (eg .CommandText = "Some SQL statement";)

}
```

There is a code example from Microsoft Docs how to capture string literal:

```csharp
// Use the syntax model to find the literal string:
LiteralExpressionSyntax helloWorldString = root.DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<LiteralExpressionSyntax>()
    .Single();

// Use the semantic model for type information:
TypeInfo literalInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(helloWorldString);
```

But I'm not sure how to get from the reference of type `SymbolCallerInfo` to a property `CommandText` to the string that is assigned to it?

Comment: Is their a specific reason why you are not doing this in a standard Roslyn analyzer?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Yes. I would like to process/analyze results programmatically outside of realm of C#/Visual Studio. But if you have an idea how to do it in analyzer, I think I can figure how to translate it for my use-case.

Comment: FYI: You don't need Visual Studio to run an analyzer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926915/run-roslyn-code-analyzers-on-build-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for a `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` that has syntax for the `CommandText` property as its `Left` expression.

You can find that syntax from the `Locations` property of the `SymbolCallerInfo reference` you have, but in my experience it's easier to work the other way around.

You're looking for text being assigned to a property, so I would search for `AssignmentExpressionSyntax`.

In an Analyzer, you would override the `Initialize` method as follows:

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);

    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
        AnalyzeAssignmentExpression, SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression);
}
```

Note that we're only looking for simple assignments here; i.e. assignments using `=`. I suppose you could consider looking for `SyntaxKind.AddAssignmentExpression` as well, i.e. assignments using `+=`, but it would be less easy to determine what exactly is the value being assigned, so I left that out.

So now we need to implement the `AnalyzeAssignmentExpression` method.

```cs
private void AnalyzeAssignmentExpression(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
```

The first thing we do is get the `AssignmentExpressionSyntax node` we're analyzing:

```cs
private void AnalyzeAssignmentExpression(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var node = (AssignmentExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
```

That node has `Left` and `Right` properties we need to look at. Let's start with the `Left` property, and find out what symbol this refers to.

```cs
    ISymbol left = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(
        node.Left, context.CancellationToken).Symbol;
```

We need to find out if this Symbol is indeed our `CommandText` property.

Here's a small helper method that will do just that:

```cs
private static bool IsCommandText(ISymbol symbol)
    => symbol is IPropertySymbol
    {
        Name: "CommandText",
        ContainingType:
        {
            Name: "SqlCommand",
            ContainingNamespace:
            {
                Name: "SqlClient",
                ContainingNamespace:
                {
                    Name: "Data",
                    ContainingNamespace:
                    {
                        // Allow both Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.SqlClient
                        ContainingNamespace:
                        {
                            IsGlobalNamespace: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

(You could also compare its `ContainingType` to a symbol you looked up once using `Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName()`, if you know the exact type you're looking for. I didn't, so I used this pattern.)

Using that helper method, we can test our `left` symbol. If it's not our `CommandText` property, we can stop analyzing this `node`.

```cs
    if (!IsCommandText(left))
    {
        return;
    }
```

Now let's look at the `Right` property, the syntax being assigned. You said you're looking for a `LiteralExpressionSyntax`, but I would suggest you look at any syntax that evaluates to a constant string. It doesn't have to be a literal. It could be the name of a constant for example, a concatenation of two literals, or many other kinds of expressions. But I would think that all you really care about, is its value. So let's see if the `Right` property has a constant string value. (I am assuming you're not interested is the value `null` here.) If it has a constant string value, we have found what we're looking for.

```cs
    var right = context.SemanticModel.GetConstantValue(node.Right, context.CancellationToken);

    if (right.HasValue && right.Value is string value)
    {
        // value is a constant being assigned to SqlCommand.CommandText
        // your further analysis goes here
    }
}
```

The entire method:

```cs
private void AnalyzeAssignmentExpression(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var node = (AssignmentExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

    ISymbol left = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(
        node.Left, context.CancellationToken).Symbol;

    if (!IsCommandText(left))
    {
        return;
    }

    var right = context.SemanticModel.GetConstantValue(node.Right, context.CancellationToken);

    if (right.HasValue && right.Value is string value)
    {
        // value is a constant being assinged to SqlCommand.CommandText
        // your further analysis goes here
    }
}
```

If you're not doing this in an analyzer, you can find the `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` nodes using `root.DescendantNodes().OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>()`, and from your question I take it you already know how to get the `SemanticModel` for them.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks! For me, the "bridge" between two approaches was to use `DescendantNodes` overload accepting `TextSpan` from my `SymbolFinder` results: `root.DescendantNodes(reference.Location.SourceSpan).OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>();`